# Run jQuery Plugin after ajax form success

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I use jqueryForm plugin for updating an image without reloading page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbtn').click(function() {
        $("#viewimage").html('');
        $("#viewimage").html('Uploading...');
            $(".uploadform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#viewimage',
            }).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Afterwards i want to use imgAreaSelect plugin (that works perfect when solo)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '166:90',
        minHeight: 90,
        minWidth: 166,
        onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);            
            $('input[name="width"]').val(selection.x2-selection.x1);
            $('input[name="height"]').val(selection.y2-selection.y1);        
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now second pluting doesn't work.

It seems that i have to use imgAreaSelect function right after jQuery Form success (there is such callback function in jQuery form [documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object). Is it right way of thinking? How i have to do it? Thank you.

Comment: It's typically better to use the submit event rather than the click event, otherwise you have to prevent the submit event from happening when the user presses enter on an input.

Comment: And yes, you should be using the callbacks provided by the ajaxForm plugin, not the global ajax events.

Comment: Yes, Kevin, i will do it! Great idea, thanks!

Comment: Kevin, posted something that helps me below, can you check it please?

Comment: Definitely not the way i would have solved it, but it'l work.

Comment: So it is not the best decision, how i can code it with callback function provided by plugin?

Comment: the same way it is done in the documentation examples.

Comment: Found, thank you, Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plugin the way it was intended to be used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".uploadform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#viewimage',
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            // this happens before the ajax request
            $("#viewimage").html('Uploading...');
        },
        success: function () {
            // this happens after the ajax request
            $('img').imgAreaSelect({...}); // removed options for this sample, add them back in your code.
        }
    });
});
```

You don't need click events or submit events, or even to trigger the submit event, this all gets handled by the plugin. This piece of code replaces both code snippets in your question.